# Busy Waiting using semaphore

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, semaphore

I am doing some synchronization thread using semaphores. Now I have to do is wait  until some customer thread arrive in queue using semaphores in floor_clerk thread. I was previously doing it using while loop. And customer thread have to wait also until it is assisted by floor_clerk using semaphore also. I was previously doing it using deep sleep.
**Any wait must be implemented using P(semaphores) (acquire)** this is how waiting should be done.
This is the task:
**Floor clerks wait (use semaphores) for customers to arrive; then, they help them with whatever information they need. However, floor clerks can only help one customer at a time; therefore, a customer must wait (use semaphores) for an available clerk to help him/her.**

My previous Floor_clerk code for waiting is:

```
while (done != Main.csize) {        
    //wait while their is no customer in queue
    while (queue.isEmpty() && done != Main.csize) {
    }

    //while their is a customer in queue assist customers
    while (queue.size() != 0 && done != Main.csize) {
        //some stuff to do
    }
}
```

Please help me implement semaphores here.

Comment: Please help me somebody??

Answer (score 0):

Just store your clients in a blocking queue, and use the `take()` method to block until there is a client available to serve. There's no need to separate the queue and the blocking mechanism since it's already built into the library.

If you must use a Semaphore, Semaphores work by having basically a blocking queue of "permits." You should think about how this blocking functionality might fit into what you're trying to do. When there is a client available, you want to `release()` a permit and allow for the service to `acquire()`. If there aren't any permits, then the service will block on `acquire()`.

```
// Add client
queue.add(client);
semaphore.release();

// Clerk loop
while (true) { // Whatever condition
    semaphore.acquire(); 
    Client client = queue.remove();
    // ...
}
```